# Error OCI8 codeigniter 3

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, php7

Hola amigos tengo un error en CodeIgniter 3

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: Module 'oci8' already loaded
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

no e encontrado ninguna solución solo doy permisos a algunas carpetas de 777 para ver si es ese el error pero realmente no se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La soluciona este error, es que se debe verificar que no se este utilizando oci8 o se este llamando en otro lado por ejmplo en mi caso tenia "extension = oci8.so" en un archivo en apache toca tener cuidado donde se inicia esta extension ya que se inicia en lados diferentes.